# How can I delete duplicates in a C# list<list<int>>?

Tags: c#, list

How can I remove lists duplicated by values?

[LeetCode 15. 3sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usJ72.png)

[Two screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNMdM.png)

Input:

```
nums = [-1,0,1,2,-1,4]
```

Output:

```
[[-1,0,1],[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]
```

Expected output:

```
[[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]
```

I need to delete lists with equal values (for example, [[1,2,3],[2,3,1]] are equal).

[0,0,0] equals [0,0,0] too.

```
public IList<IList<int>> ThreeSum(int[] nums)
{
    var res = new List<IList<int>>();
    var set = new HashSet<IList<int>>();
    Array.Sort(nums);
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < nums.Length; j++)
        {
            if (j + 1 >= nums.Length) break;
            var neededInt = 0 - (nums[i] + nums[j]);
            var k = Array.BinarySearch(nums, j+1, nums.Length - j - 1, neededInt);
            if (k < 0) continue;
            else
            {
                var list = new List<int> { nums[i], nums[j], nums[k] };
                list.Sort();
                if (!set.Contains(list))
                {
                    res.Add(list);
                    set.Add(list);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public int BinarySearch(int[] arr, int query,int left, int right)
{
    while (left < right)
    {
        var middle = (right + left) / 2;
        if(query <= arr[middle])
        {
            right = middle;
        }
        else
        {
            left = middle + 1;
        }
    }
    if (query == arr[left])
        return left;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Does order matter? E.g. does `{1, 2, 3}` equal `{2, 3, 1}` or not?

Comment: can you add example data and expected with text ?( your example pic is incomprehensible)

Comment: yes, {1, 2, 3} equal {2, 3, 1}

Comment: Now you have given (almost) the description of the problem as it appears on [leetcode 3sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/). But you did not explain what your problem with this challenge is. When trying to run your code, I am getting **ArgumentOutOfRangeException**, is that the problem you are facing ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`DistinctBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-7.0) in order to remove sub-lists with equal sums:

```cs
var input = new[] {
    new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, // sum: 6
    new[] { 3, 2, 1 }, // sum: 6
    new[] { 2, 4, 0 }, // sum: 6
    new[] { 1, 2, 4 }, // sum: 7
    new[] { 0, 2, 5 }, // sum: 7
};

var result = input.DistinctBy(x => x.Sum()).ToArray();

Debug.Assert(result.Length == 2);
Debug.Assert(result[0].SequenceEqual(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }));
Debug.Assert(result[1].SequenceEqual(new[] { 1, 2, 4 }));
```